# vuejs: router-link params is empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have defined a router-link

```
<router-link :to="{ path: linkTo + '/' + item.name, params: { id: item.id } }" >{{item.name}}</router-link>
```

But when I inspect the router-link, the params object is always empty.

[image]
What i'm doing wrong? If I just output the id with {{item.id}} i get the number...

This is my route

```
{ path: '/category/:name', component: Category, props: true, name: 'category', meta: { auth: true } },
```

gregor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic segment specified in your route is "name", not the "id". This means your $route.params object doesn't have an "id" property and you can't access it with props in your child component.

You have either to change path in your route to `path: '/category/:id'` or change your router-link params to `params: { name: item.id }`. Don't forget to add `props: ['id']` (or `props: ['name']`) in your child component.

Comment: Ah ok but is there a way how i can keep the real name in the path (for easier reading) and send the id under the hood?

Comment: You can use 2 parameters in route: path: `'/category/:name/:id'` (but path will be longer and less readable though)